# Xbox 360 Security - Why must you be the data owner to move content?

Tags: storage

Xbox 360 does not allow you to move content (such as to a usb), unless you are the owner of the content (Same gamertag as save file). This seems pointless considering, I can simply sign into any account on my Xbox anyway, so the only thing this security seems to do is slow me down when I'm trying to move a mass amount of files from one Xbox to another.

Is there an actual security reason for implementing such security practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to prevent you moving content belonging to another profile that has been password protected.

As you mention, this does not provide much security if the profiles are not so protected, because you can just switch between them: but having the XBox behave differently depending on whether the password is set or not adds complexity, which costs money and risks adding bugs. Remember too that some of content has DRM attached to it, adding to the complexity and requirements.

And it's not necessarily about security. Won't most XBox users only have a single profile? Won't most people moving content in multiple profiles be replacing the hardware in a shared XBox, and so can use Microsoft´s migration tool? So won't most users never encounter the scenario you have?

As an advanced user, of course, you have perfectly good reasons for having multiple profiles, and even better ones for not using Microsoft's tool, but it's hard for Microsoft engineers to justify features that only advanced users need in such a low margin product.

Comment: But, on my Xbox specifically the accounts are not password protected, so this protection does nothing but inconvenience the user. Is this solution ideal to be used, or should they have better checking to see if accounts have such security.

Comment: Updated answer to hopefully address this point.